# Parsing the pst file for the owner

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, outlook, pst

I am analyzing a Microsoft Outlook PST file using python 3 and I need to find out who owns this mailbox. The name of the owner and the name of his mailbox are enough for me. Please tell me, is it possible to find out using python 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no specific property or marker which could help identifying the owner. PST is just a storage, it doesn't belong to anybody. For example, it may keep forwarded items and be used like an archive. So, trying to find the answer on checking its items, like Dmitry mentioned, may lead to incorrect results.

Answer (score 1):

A PST file (unlike a cached Outlook mailbox in an OST file) does not have an intrinsic user identity. It can be used without an email account, or with multiple POP3/SMTP accounts.

You can try to look at who received the messages in the Inbox folder (`MailItem.ReceivedByName`) or who sent the messages in the Sender Items folder (`MailItem.SenderName`/`SenderEmailAddress`)